# My button won't go to the top right corner of my screen

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm new to CSS, JavaScript, and HTML so be patient with me. I created a button that duplicates my div but the button won't go to the top right of my page. It just stays attached for the div for some reason - image attached for clarification.

[image: Button and were I'm trying to get it to go]

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
}

.nameone {
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 6px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  position: relative;
  padding: 20px;
  padding-left: 25px;
  padding-right: 25px;
  border-radius: 5%;
}

.buttonformatting {
  background-color: red;
  height: 25px;
  width: 25px;
}

.text {
  border: none;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewpoint" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
  <title>TrialV3</title>
  <link href="Style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>

  <div class="nameone">
    <input class="text" type="text" onkeypress="this.style.width = ((this.value.length + 1)*8 ) + 'px';">
  </div>

  <script>
    var i = 0;
    var original = document.querySelector('.nameone');

    function duplicate() {
      var clone = original.cloneNode(true);
      clone.class = ".nameone" + ++i;
      original.parentNode.appendChild(clone);
    }
  </script>

  <button id="buttonone" onclick=duplicate() class="buttonformatting">
    </button>

</body>

<button id="buttonone" onclick=duplicate() class="buttonformatting">
    </button>

</html>
```

I have tried placing  outside of my  so it doesn't get affected by that centering. I also tried putting inside of the body. However I arrange it, it seems like the button doesn't want to leave the div's side.

Comment: Your second `button` element is outside `body` area,

Comment: Thank @MisterJojo! Completely forgot I left that in there. However, the button still doesn't want to do to the top right

Comment: I didn't not understand, you need to use **two** buttons ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why would it go to the top right unless you specify it?
`position: absolute; top: 20px; right: 20px` also consider `position: fixed`

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
}

.nameone {
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 6px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  position: relative;
  padding: 20px;
  padding-left: 25px;
  padding-right: 25px;
  border-radius: 5%;
}

.buttonformatting {
  background-color: red;
  height: 25px;
  width: 25px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  right: 20px;
}

.text {
  border: none;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewpoint" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
  <title>TrialV3</title>
  <link href="Style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>

  <div class="nameone">
    <input class="text" type="text" onkeypress="this.style.width = ((this.value.length + 1)*8 ) + 'px';">
  </div>

  <script>
    var i = 0;
    var original = document.querySelector('.nameone');

    function duplicate() {
      var clone = original.cloneNode(true);
      clone.class = ".nameone" + ++i;
      original.parentNode.appendChild(clone);
    }
  </script>

  <button id="buttonone" onclick=duplicate() class="buttonformatting">
    </button>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

CSS Code:

```css
#buttonone {
  position   : absolute;  /* prefer use absolute to avoid scroll pb */
  top        : 20px;
  right      : 20px;
  background : red;
  height     : 25px;
  width      : 25px;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewpoint" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
  <title>TrialV3x</title>
<style>
body {
  margin          : 0;
  display         : flex;
  justify-content : center;
  align-items     : center;
  height          : 100vh;
  }
.nameone {
  box-shadow    : 0px 0px 6px -1px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
  padding       : 20px;
  padding-left  : 25px;
  padding-right : 25px;
  border-radius : 5%;
  }
#buttonone {
  position   : absolute;  /* prefer use absolute to avoid scroll pb */
  top        : 20px;
  right      : 20px;
  background : red;
  height     : 25px;
  width      : 25px;
  }
.text-in {
  border     : none;
  text-align : center;
  width      : var(--txt-w);
  }
</style>
</head>
<body>

  <div class="nameone">
    <input class="text-in" type="text" style="--txt-w:80px">
  </div>
  <button id="buttonone"></button>

<script>
  const
    original = document.querySelector('.nameone')
  , btDuplic = document.querySelector('#buttonone')
  , txtInSz0 = parseInt(document.querySelector('.text-in').style.getPropertyValue('--txt-w'))
    ;
  original.counter = 1
    ; 
  btDuplic.addEventListener('click', () =>
    {
    let clone       = original.cloneNode(true);
    clone.classList.add("num-"  + original.counter); // or className
    original.parentNode.append(clone);
    });
  document.addEventListener('keydown', ({target:elm}) =>
    {
    if (!elm.matches('input.text-in')) return;
    let newLen = Math.max( txtInSz0 , ((1+elm.value.length)*8)) + 'px';
    elm.style.setProperty('--txt-w',newLen)
    })
</script>
</body>
</html>
```